# objective C function with int array return value and input value

Tags: c#, objective-c

I am new to objective C, and trying to create a function for an iPhone app. However, I am having a hard time to create this C# function in Objective C. Specifically the correct syntax to pass the integer array and to get it back, I just keep getting lost between the array, * and NSArray / NSMutableArray, NSInteger[], etc.

THe best I came up with was, which doesn't work, is:

```
- (NSInteger[])GetUniqueNumbers: (NSInteger *)nums[] WithMin: (int) min WithMax: (int) max;
{
return nums;
}
```

The original C# function:

```
private int[] GetUniqueNumbers(int[] nums, int min, int max)
{
    int[] NewNumbers = new int[nums.Length];

    for(int i=0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        int trynum = nums[i];

        while(ExistsAlready(NewNumbers, trynum) == true)
        {
            trynum = trynum + 1;
            if (trynum > max)
            {
                trynum = min;
            }
        }

        NewNumbers[i] = trynum;

    }

return NewNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
- (NSArray *)GetUniqueNumbers:(NSArray *)nums WithMin:(NSInteger)min WithMax:(NSInteger)max{
    NSMutableArray *NewNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0; i<[nums count]; i++){
        NSInteger trynum = [[nums objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
        while([NewNumbers containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trynum]]){
            trynum = trynum + 1;
            if (trynum > max){
                trynum = min;
            }
        }
        [NewNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:trynum]];
    }
    return NewNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way we write Method in objective c

```
- (NSArray *)GetUniqueNumbers: (NSArray *)nums WithMin: (int) min WithMax: (int) max;
{
return nums;
}
```